# Terms of use for functions that access data over the internet

Tags: functions, web-access, webservices, apifunction

Please excuse, as this is not a question about how to use a specific Mathematica function
or solve some specific problem with Mathematica. But, a correct and comprehensive answer might
be of interest for a lot of users, as it seems to be difficult to find one in the web or
in the official documentation.

To be concrete: Using the taxonomy of Mathematica functions detailed below, how is it possible
to find out for a specific function,
to which part of the taxonomy it belongs and especially if the number of calls/month
is limited or liable to payment for buying the right to execute a certain number of calls/month.

I ask as a Mathematica Home Edition user with a standard Desktop license (for version 13.2).

1. Functions which do not access data over the net for execution ("strictly local").

Examples:

Classical CAS functions:

```
Integrate[Sin[x]^2, x]

Factor[x^30 - 1]
```

2. Functions which access data over the net for execution ("non local").

Examples:

A. EntityFunctions giving information about geography or generally the physical world:

Aa. Geoinfos:

```
countryList = EntityList["Country"]

continent = EntityProperty[ "Country", "Continent"]

europe = EntityClass["Country", "Europe"]

countryListEurope = Select[countryList, #[continent] == europe &]

Map[{#, #["GDP"], #["Population"]} &, countryListEurope]

GeoGraphics[countryListEurope]

uluru = Entity["Mountain", "Uluru"]

EntityProperties[uluru]

uluru["Position"]
```

Ab. Physical constants

```
Entity["PhysicalConstant", "ElectronMass"]["Value"]
```

B. Functions where, seemingly, neural network description and configuration data is downloaded
(and cached locally, if I understand that rightly):

```
FacialFeatures[img]
ImageIdentify[img2]
```

C. Web Searches

```
WebImageSearch["Pope Francis", Method -> "Google"]
```

D. Sound (I am not sure, if internet data download takes place).

```
Sound[Table[SoundNote[RandomInteger[{0, 12}], 0.2, "Cello"], {15}]]

Speak["This is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country"]
```

How can one determine into which of the following categories each of these functions above (and similar ones not mentioned) fall?

2.1. Free (no payment necessary and possible) functions

2.1.1 Limited number of accesses/month

2.1.2 Unlimited number of accesses

2.2. Liable to payment

2.2.1 Limited number of accesses/month, payment included in price for Mathematica license

2.2.2 Unlimited number of accesses, payment included in price for Mathematica license

2.2.3 Unlimited number of accesses, liable to pay every access or block of accesses